# How many ways are there to select 4 students if the committee must include at least one science and at least one engineering student?

Tags: combinatorics

A student committee of 4 is to be elected from a class of 3 engineering
students and 4 science students. How many ways are there to select 4
students if the committee must include at least one science and at least
one engineering student?

Am I right in doing the following:

$$\  3C1 \times  4C1 \times 2C1 \times 3C1 = 72 \ $$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is not correct---there are only $^7C_4=35$ ways to choose four students even if we did not care for the restriction, so how can there be more ways once we include the restriction? An easy way to do the question is by counting the complement set, i.e. the number of ways to choose the committee so that either there are no science students, or no engineering students. It is not really possible that there are no science students, since there are only $3$ engineering students and we need $4$ committee members, and there is exactly one way to choose a committee with no engineering students---by choosing all $4$ science students. So the answer is $35-1=34$.

The flaw in your logic is that you counted some cases too many times. For example $^3C_1\cdot{}^4C_1$ is not really the same as choosing two science students, since the order doesn't matter. Similarly $^2C_1\cdot{}^3C_1$ is not the same as choosing two engineering students. Furthermore  you are assuming that there must be $2$ students from science and engineering respectively, which is not necessarily true.

Comment: Thank-you that makes a-lot of sense